# MySQL uses last opened connection

Tags: php, mysql

On an older application of ours we see strange behaviour since a while.

We have multiple pages which require the data of multiple databases, everything has worked fine until recently.

If we need need multiple database we  initialize them like so:

```
$linkDatabaseOne = fConnectToDatabase( "Database1" );
$linkDatabaseTwo = fConnectToDatabase( "Database2" );
```

And after that we execute the queries like this:

```
mysql_query( "QUERY", $linkDatabaseOne );
mysql_query( "QUERY", $linkDatabaseTwo );
```

The fConnectToDatabase function

```
function fConnectToDatabase( $Server = null ) {
    switch( $Server ) {
        case "Database2":
            $link = @mysql_connect ( "localhost", "USER", "PW" )
            or die ("No connection");
            mysql_select_db("Database2");
        break;
        case "Database1":
                       $link = @mysql_connect ( "localhost", "USER", "PW" )
                       or die ("No connection");
                       mysql_select_db("Database1");
        break;
   }
     return $link;
 }
```

But the problem is that at this moment both queries will be thrown at Database2, because that one has the last openend connection.

Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

Comment: You should replace `mysql_*` with `PDO` since `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: Show us the code or documentation for fConnectToDatabase ;-)

Comment: Houssni I am aware of that, but in this current situation I have to life with this. If it were up to me I would rebuild the entire application, but unfortunately it isnt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this you need to establish your configuration like this:

```
   $dbcon2 = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

free the resultsets

```
    $linkDatabaseOne = fConnectToDatabase( "Database1" );
    mysql_query( "QUERY", $linkDatabaseOne );
    mysql_free_result( $linkDatabaseOne );

    $linkDatabaseTwo = fConnectToDatabase( "Database2" );
    mysql_query( "QUERY", $linkDatabaseTwo );
    mysql_free_result( $linkDatabaseTwo );
```